# Memory Mapping File C# in Web Farm

Tags: wcf, caching, memory-mapped-files, web-farm-framework

I have a web service developed in WCF and its deployed as a Web Farm(3 servers). We are trying to implement caching using MemoryMappedFile. How does memory mapping behave in Web Farm. Is there any option to manage the MemoryMappedFile across servers?

Comment: Rhetorical question: do your machines share memory? No, they don't, so this won't work. Why not use a tool like memcached?

Comment: How do i share memory ?

Comment: You can't (at least not trivially), it was a rhetorical question to set you on the right path.

Comment: Can i create a Persistent memory mapping file in a share location and access it across servers? Is it a good approach?

Comment: take a look at Redis; you should be using that or a similar caching service.

Comment: Why are you planning to do it by yourself ? have you looked at other caching solutions like memcached or Redis ? you can install and run a Redis instance on windows server too.

Answer (score 1):

If you task is to do caching between servers, memory mapped file will not be good solution.

You can use proper caching solution like [Redis](http://redis.io/) for that.

You will also need c# library to communicate with Redis, you can use this one:  https://servicestack.net/redis